# empty string from DB to null ??? if($var === null){ statement}

Tags: laravel, null, isset, is-empty

I im chechking DB if there is record. and if there is no recod i wanna make one. But i cant get NULL from DB i got empty string. how can i solve this?

```
public function chechk_slots(){
    $character_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $inv_user = DB::table("slots")->where('character_id', $character_id)->get();
    return $inv_user?? null ;
}
```

and

```
public function to_inventary()
{

    $a = "Is record";
    $b = "there is no record";

    $character_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $inv_items = DB::table("items_chars")->where('character_id', $character_id)->get();
    $user_profile = $this->show_profile();
    $slot = $this->chechk_slots();
    //dd($slot);
    //DB::table("slots")->insert(['character_id' => $character_id]);
   // dd($slot[0]->character_id);
    if($slot === null){
        dd($b);
        DB::table("slots")->insert(['character_id' => $character_id]);
    }
    else{
        dd($a);
    }
    //return view('inventary', compact('user_profile', 'inv_items'));
}
```

my table in DB pic [image]
There is no record 
if I dd($slot); i got this pic [image]

so empty string !=null and cant get a record...How can i change this?

Comment: Can you share migration files?

Comment: I dont have migration files for this, i dont use them... dont know even how to do that :)

Comment: Looks like your DB is empty

Answer (score 0):

## Issue #1 - Collection

You will get a collection even if it has no data.

```php
$inv_user = DB::table("slots")->where('character_id', $character_id)->get();
```

## Issue #2 - Null coalescing

It similar to the ternary operator, but will behave like `isset` on the lefthand operand instead of just using its boolean value.

```php
$inv_user = DB::table("slots")->where('character_id', $character_id)->get();

return $inv_user ?? null;
```

`$inv_user` assigned `Illuminate\Support\Collection`.

---

## Solution

Use `count()` and ternary operator.

```php
public function chechk_slots(){
    $character_id = Auth::id();
    $inv_user = DB::table("slots")->where('character_id', $character_id)->count();

    return $inv_user ?: null ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you want to get null from the query just use **first()** instead of **get()** and return the result in one line

```
return DB::table("slots")->where('character_id', $character_id)->first();
```